# SQLAlchemy Three Many-To-Many relations in one elegant query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to do a query in sqlalchemy through three many-to-many relations, joining them and getting only unique records?

My setup is following:

- Command - something a user can perform
- User - a person Group - group
  of users for easy distribution of commands
- UserGroup - N:N
  relationship between users and groups
- UserCommand - N:N relationship
  between users and commands
- GroupCommand - N:N relationship between
  groups and commands

See the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    ForeignKey
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    relationship,
    backref
)


Base = declarative_base()


class Command(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'commands'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = relationship('User', secondary='users_commands')
    groups = relationship('Group', secondary='groups_commands')


class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    groups = relationship('Group', secondary='users_groups')
    commands = relationship('Command', secondary='users_commands')


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = relationship('User', secondary='users_groups')
    commands = relationship('Command', secondary='groups_commands')


class UserGroup(Base):
    """Many-To-Many on users and groups"""

    __tablename__ = 'users_groups'

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), primary_key=True)
    user = relationship('User', backref=backref('user_groups', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
    user_group = relationship('UserGroup', backref=backref('user_groups', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))


class UserCommand(Base):
    """Many-to-many on users and commands"""

    __tablename__ = 'users_commands'

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    command_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('commands.id'), primary_key=True)
    user = relationship('User', backref=backref('user_commands', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
    command = relationship('Command', backref=backref('user_commands', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))


class GroupCommand(Base):
    """Many-to-many on groups and commands"""

    __tablename__ = 'groups_commands'

    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), primary_key=True)
    command_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('commands.id'), primary_key=True)
    group = relationship('Group', backref=backref('group_commands', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
    command = relationship('Command', backref=backref('group_commands', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
```

I want to get all commands for one user, first based on groups the user is in and then based on user specific commands. E.g. pseudocode:

- User[1] belongs to the Group[1, 2]
- User[1] itself has Command[1, 2]
- Group[1] has Command[2, 3], Group[2] has Command[3, 4]
- I want the query to return Command[1, 2, 3, 4]

I am able to do it via two separate queries and list/set unique join:

```
commands_user_specific = session.query(Command).\
                             join(Command.users).\
                             join(User.groups).\
                             filter(User.id == self.user.id).all()

commands_group_specific = session.query(Command).\
                              join(Command.groups).\
                              join(Group.users).\
                              filter(User.id == self.user.id).all()

commands = commands_user_specific +\
               list(set(commands_group_specific) - set(commands_user_specific))
```

However I believe that there is also some more elegant way, with ".join" or even through ".filter", which I prefer to use.

Thank you for your insights